# Express entire functions $f(z)$ by exact formula

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

An entire function $f(z)$ has the properties that $f(0)=10,f'(0)=0$, and $f''(1+ \frac{1}{n})=2- \frac{3}{n}$ for each $n=1,2,3,...$ Express $f(z)$ by an exact formula and prove that it is the unique function with these conditions.

My work: Since $f(z)$ is entire, define $g(z)= f ''(z)-5+3z$, and so, we have $g(1+\frac{1}{n})=0$. Thus by uniqueness theorem, we obtain $f''(z)=5-3z$.  Therefore, $f'(z)=5z-\frac{3z^2}{2}+a$.  since $f'(0)=0$, so we get $f(z)=\frac{5z^2}{2}-\frac{z^3}{2}+b$, Since $f(0)=10$, we thus obtain, $f(z)=\frac{5z^2}{2}-\frac{z^3}{2}+10$. Did i miss anything? How to prove that it is unique functions with these conditions? Your kind help will appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: Take another $f$ and reread your argument with it. You get the se formula for $f$.

Comment: You just did: "By the uniqueness theorem, we *obtain* " (not "we *guess* ")

Comment: I did not get your point. Could you please give more specific idea? I appreciate your kind concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you did is fine. In order to prove that it is unique, suppose that $g$ satisfies the same conditions. Then, by the identity theorem, $g''=f''$. Therefore $g'-f'$ is constant. But $g'(0)=f'(0)$ and therefore $g'-f'=0$. So, $g-f$ is constant. But $g(0)-f(0)=0$ and therefore $g-f=0$, that is, $g=f$.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Ricky If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: I am extremely sorry! I did not notice the left button. I am new in this great platform. I appreciate your kind help. Thank you again!